# String replaceALL with conditions on letters before and after the match

Tags: java, regex, conditional-statements, replaceall

I am reading in Strings from a text file

Example: Is Mississippi a State where there are a lot of Systems?

I am trying to use replace all to replace all "s" & "S" with the same case "t" or "T" unless at the start of a word and unless before or after the "s" or "S" there is another "s" or "S".

Output expected: It Mississippi a State where there are a lot of Syttemt?

I have tried...

```
.replaceAll("[^sStT](?!\\b)S", "T").replaceAll("[^SstT](?!\\b)s", "t");
```

The output was..."t Mtstsippi a State where there are many Sttet?"

Comment: .replaceAll("[^sStT](?!\\b)S", "T").replaceAll("[^SstT](?!\\b)s", "t");  The output was..."t Mtstsippi a State where there are many Sttet?"

Comment: And what output does that give you?

Comment: Add the additional information (your code, and the resulting output) to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @RealSkeptic :new to the system...thanks for the information...I put it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two `replaceAll` calls. one for `s -> t` and one for `S -> T`

You can use a look-behind `(?<=regex)` and look-ahead `(?=regex)` group to find a pattern without replacing its contents.

The look-behind will check that a character before `s` is not in a list of characters `[^<list>]`. This list includes the start character `^` and `sS` and `tT` and whitespace `\\s`

`(?<=[^^\\ssStT])`

The look-ahead will do a similar check, but only verify the next character is not `sS`

`(?=[^sS])`

Putting this all together:

```
String test = "Is Mississippi a State where there are a lot of Systems?";
System.out.println(test
        .replaceAll("(?<=[^^\\ssStT])s(?=[^sS])","t")
        .replaceAll("(?<=[^^\\ssStT])S(?=[^sS])","T")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there is already an accepted answer but here is another method to achieve what you want using a little java hack and negative lookbehind/after.

```
String s = "Is Mississippi a State where there are a lot of Systems?";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<![ sS])(s|S)(?![sS])", Character.isUpperCase("$1".charAt(0)) ? "T" : "t");
System.out.println(s); // It Mississippi a State where there are a lot of Syttemt?
```

Comment: I'm confused how `"$1".charAt(0)` actually gets its value.. wouldn't `$1` be evaluated before `replaceAll` is invoked?

Comment: Actually I just tested this with capital chars! that second parameter is always being evaluated as `"t"` in all cases. You're looking at the `"$"`

Comment: @flkes You're right. What do you think would be the solution?

Comment: Doing the two calls to replace i suppose. Not sure how you'd do this for a single replaceAll